# Spring request body problem with non-valid xml

Tags: java, string, spring, rest, inputstream

In our rest application we use @RequestBody StreamSorce to upload xml file. The problem is that is xml itself is non-valid or contains some invalid characters, PUT request is failing(with http bad request response) before our logic, so we can not inform client about exact problem. I know that it is possible to use just plain String for requestBody, but does it make sense to use it? I guess if i will upload 100Mb xml each request will create String request body with same size, and while using StreamSource we are reading input stream while we need it.

What are the cons and pros for using String or StreamSource as requestbody. If i do it with StreamSorce will it scan the whole xml?

Comment: What sort of invalid characters are you talking about? If the XML is not well-formed - will it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You already know the con of the StreamSource: in makes it not possible for you to pre-process the XML, in case it is invalid.

Using String: when XML would be so large, it would be a performance killer! Never use so large objects in Java - in multi-thread environment of application server it can easily lead to `OutOfMemoryError`, it makes your application vulnerable to **DoS** attack!

The best solution is to map `@RequestBody` as `InputStream`, and process that `InputStream` with **SAX** parser. You have low memory consumption (SAX parser doesn't store XML structure in memory) and you can handle exceptions, that can be thrown during the processing.